# JS function triggered without being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a Phonegap App, using jQuery and jQuery Mobile.

In some page I've bound a function to a tap event, but the function is triggered when the page loads.
After debuging a little (using `arguments.callee.caller.caller.toString()`) I discovered that, for some crazy reason, a click event is being triggered in that button just when the page is loaded.

When I changed the footer's class, the problem had gone (also my styling), then I changed the class references in my CSS file to match the new footer class, the problem came back. This is very strange, maybe it have something with my CSS.

There's no any other reference to `"footer_body"` in my project.

If I set the function calls directly on the HTML(something like `<span onClick="javascript:obj.leftMethod()">`), I have the same behavior.

For sure it's a Phonegap/Android issue, as this doesn't happen in a PC browser (besides I have to comment a lot of code which only work in mobile).

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="footer_body">
   <span class="left"><span>Text 1</span></span>
   <span class="right"><span>Text 2</span></span>
</div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
function PageClass() {
...
    // called when the page is loaded
    this.init = function() {
        $(".footer_body", "#page_2").find(".left").unbind("tap").bind("tap", function() {
            that.leftMethod();
        });

        $(".footer_body", "#page_2").find(".right").unbind("tap").bind("tap", function() {
            that.rightMethod();
        });
        // that is a reference to "this" of the class
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `debugger; ` first line in your `leftMethod()/rightMethod()` functions. Open in Chrome and when it loads, press `Ctrl+Shift+I` it'll popup an inspector with a paused Scripts tab where you get the whole stacktrace (caller, callee, events, etc)

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL, I'm using Phonegap.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Try it anyway.

Comment: I did it, but the function didn't show up in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I debugged myself, looking for arguments.callee.caller.toString() and arguments.callee.caller.caller.toString(), and seems the click event is really being triggered.

Comment: So _what_ is the question, pray tell?

Comment: @jcolebrand, sorry, but what you're talking about?  My question is in the first line.

Comment: but you've been editing again and again, I'm confused what you've determined is working and what isn't. I was hoping you would refactor the question, to indicate what you've done and not done, and what you still need help with, with the final question at the bottom.

Comment: I just edited 2 or 3 times and those edits didn't changed the core of my question. **My problem is yet the same**, but as I discovered some issues, I added those edits. I don't know what I done wrong.
My last discovery was that this issue is caused by a "automaticly" click event in the page loading.

Comment: You should create a reduction of the problem in http://jsfiddle.net It's nearly impossible to guess with what you've provided.

Comment: @JuanMendes, I'm almost sure this is a Phonegap/Android issue, as this problem doens't appear when I test on PC browsers.

Comment: Creating a reduction is the best way to be sure, it doesn't look like anyone is going to help you with this question as is. You often find the solution yourself by creating a reduction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question near to be solved. The real problem is that all touch events are being carried to the next pages. I didn't noticed that before, seemed it were something like a auto click, but was the previous screen touch event that triggered the current page touch event.

Sure it's a Android or Phonegap bug - More info about it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/Iii6K0aXcXE/T1ZKQsMtB-UJ), in case of someone have the same perception I had from this problem.

I still in need of a concrete solution, but I'm tired of investigating this, so I temporarily solved this setting a short delay to activate the listener functions.